# Accessing members of a derived class from a factory created instance

Tags: c++, scope, polymorphism, factory, encapsulation

I have a simple `Shape` factory example where I can create `Circle`s or `Square`s.

I have added an extra "`contents`" attribute to the `Circle` class that is not part of the `Square` derived class or the `Shape` base class.

The problem is, when I create an instance of the `Circle` class using my factory, I am unable to modify the `contents` of the created object.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Shape base clas
class Shape {
public:

    // Shape constructor;
    Shape() {
        id_ = total_++;
    }

    // Virtual draw method
    virtual void draw() = 0;

protected:

    int id_;
    static int total_;
};
int Shape::total_ = 0;

// Circle derived class
class Circle : public Shape {
public:
    void draw() {
        contents = 0;
        cout << "circle " << id_ << ": draw, contents: " << contents << endl;
    }

    // Attribute to attempt to access
    int contents;
};

// Square derived class
class Square : public Shape {
public:
    void draw() {
        cout << "square " << id_ << ": draw" << endl;
    }
};

// Factory class
class Factory {
public:
    Shape* createCurvedInstance() {
        return new Circle;
    }
    Shape* createStraightInstance() {
        return new Square;
    }
};

// Main
int main()
{
    Factory* factory = new Factory;
    Shape* thing = factory->createCurvedInstance();

    // Draw method works fine (as it should)
    thing->draw();

    // Fails: "expression must have class type"
    thing.contents = 4;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

**How can I access attributes of the derived class when I create an instance of it using a factory?**

Comment: You didn't think this through.  You are returning the static type `Shape*`, and all the compiler knows at compile time is `Shape*` stuff.  Since `contents` is not part of `Shape`, you get the error.  In addition, your `Shape` object should have a virtual destructor, given how you are intended to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I didn't want a factory at all!

What I really wanted was some sort of container class to hold different types of shapes.  Neither shape is derived from the `ShapeContainer` class but both shapes can be accessed through it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Circle class
class Circle {
public:
    Circle() {
        contents = 2;
    }
    void draw() {
        cout << "circle " << contents << endl;
    }

    int contents;
};

// Square class
class Square {
public:
    void draw() {
        cout << "square" << endl;
    }
};

// Shape containter class
class ShapeContainer {
public:
    Circle* getCircle() {
        return new Circle;
    }
    Square* getSquare() {
        return new Square;  
    };
};

// Main
int main()
{
    ShapeContainer* container = new ShapeContainer;
    Circle* circle = container->getCircle();

    circle->draw();
    circle->contents = 42;
    circle->draw();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This allows me to make both `Circle`s and `Square`s while still being able to access the contents of the `Circle` object!

Sometimes you need to look at things from a whole new perspective to get the functionality you really want...

Answer (score 2):

No way unless you cast, and Thou Shall Not Cast. The whole idea behind polymorphic is instances that they make themselves available through immutable interface. They highlihgt an IS-A replationship, where Circle is a Shape for all intents and purposes, except implementation details, which no one is interested in. If you add publically 'contents' to your Circle, it is no longer a Shape, so it should not be constructed through factory.

Comment: Well that sucks... I need an elegant way to do this... In my situation I have a series of individual database classes that are derived from a main database base class.  I need a way to create instances of any of the database classes (ie: through use of a factory) and access the database fields which are stored in members specific to each derived class...

Comment: Basically I need a factory that doesn't return `Shape`s. I need a factory that returns `Circle`s or `Square`s based on whichever is needed.

Comment: Like I said, your extra data should either be implementation detail, and thus you shoud not try to access from outside. Or, if you can't design a trully uniform interface, it means, there is no IS-A relationship between your classess, and factory is not applicable (it rarely is, by the way :).

Comment: Than you do not need a factory. Period. You want a specific object, with a known type.

Comment: Although I agree with SergeyA about the impossibility of using a factory in a nice way in this case, a shape with content still IS-A shape, just as a dog IS-An animal with paws, tail and snout, so that's not the problem. Even if the Derived class really IS-NOT-A Base class, that is not directly an argument against factory, but an argument against inheritance in the first place. The real 'problem' here is the point that polymorphism guarantees that you can do all Shape-y things with a pointer or reference to a Shape, *but nothing more*.

Answer (score 1):

Since a `Shape` has no `content`, **you cannot modify the `content` from a pointer to `Shape`**. full stop.

However, if you know that your particular `Shape` is in fact a `Circle` and has `content`, you can cast to a pointer to `Circle`.

```
void set_content(Shape*shape, int content)
{
  auto circle = dynamic_cast<Circle*>(shape);
  if(circle)
    circle->content = content;
}
```

This version is extra safe: it does not assume that `shape` is a `Circle*`, but uses `dynamic_cast<Circle*>`, which will return non-null only if `shape` is in fact a `Circle*`.

The `dynamic_cast<>` comes with some costs, which you may want to avoid. If you have any other fool proof way to establish that your `shape` is in fact a `Circle`, you can use a simple `static_cast<>`:

```
class Shape
{
public:
  virtual bool has_content() const { return false; }
  // ...
};

class ShapeWithContent : public Shape
{
public:
  bool has_content() const override { return true; }
  int content = 0; 
};

class Circle : public ShapeWithContent
{
  // ...
};

void set_content(Shape*shape, int content)
{
  if(shape->has_content())
    static_cast<ShapeWithContent*>(shape)->content = content;
}
```

Having said all that, I like to emphasize that you should try to design your code in a way that makes such tricks redundant/unnecessary.

Comment: Completely defeats the purpose of factory.

Comment: @SergeyA That may be so, but this was not the question.

Comment: I always feel obliged to go extra mile. Obviously, we have a learner here, so instead of showing him dirty tricks, we'd better educate him.

Comment: @SergeyA Unfortunately, '*such tricks*' are surprisingly common.

Comment: Exactly my point, @Walter! Do your share and educate people. Most of them produce bad code not because they are bad people, but because no one educated them.